# What does 'By.ID' do?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In this script,

```
location = browser.find_element(By.ID,'ctl00_cphDefaultPage_nameSearchCriteria_ddlstoreLocation')
```

Q1. What does 'By.ID' do? Cause, my original script did not have it and it didn't work but started to work only after adding this 'By.ID' to the script.

Q2. What is the difference between using 'browser' vs 'driver'

Thanks, SJ

Difference between using 'browser' vs 'driver'
and 'By.Id' function.

Comment: Did you look at [the docs?](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Answer (score 0):

The By constant represent a method to search elements in a webpage, you can search elements by their **id** (this case), classname, name, etc.

You are searching for an element like this

```
<div id="ctl00_cphDefaultPage_nameSearchCriteria_ddlstoreLocation"> </div>
```

Browser is a class that instanties a web browser and peform actions with it, like opening a web page, interacting or searching for elements, etc.

Driver is used to initialize the browser controller and set any necessary options such as browser type, controller location, etc.

Browser is high level and driver is low level asbtraction.